# How can I draw this (a tree diagram with notes on arrows) using forest?

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

[image: Model image]

Currently I can only write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {edge={->}}
[$a$
    [$3a+1$]
    [$\frac{a}{2}$]
]
\end{forest} 
\end{document}
```

which produces a similar tree to the model, just without little words beside the arrows.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by making your example compilable.

Comment: @TeXnician You mean my code snippet has errors?

Comment: No, but we appreciate helping if we have a compilable code to copy and paste that runs, i.e. we do not have to guess documentclass, packages etc. (see also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/124577)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a name to each node, then use usual `tikz` commands with them. 
I did it like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {edge={->}}
[$a$, name=root
    [$3a+1$, name=left] {\path (root)-- node [rotate=65, yshift=3pt] {\tiny left} (left) ;}
    [$\frac{a}{2}$, name=right] {\path (root)-- node [rotate=-65, yshift=3pt] {\tiny right} (right) ;}
]
\end{forest} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to use the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}    
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}
\begin{istgame}[->,sloped]
\xtdistance{20mm}{20mm}
\istroot(0)[null node]{$a$}
  \istb{\mbox{odd}}[a]{3a+1}
  \istb{\mbox{even}}[a]{\frac a2}
  \endist
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```